# How to get all members of a class in python in order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get all the members of  a class, but in order... Here's a MWE

```
class example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 3
        self.z = 5
        self.a = 5
        self.b = 3
ex = example()
members = [attr for attr in dir(ex) if not \
                   callable(getattr(ex, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]

print(members)
```

This prints:
`['a', 'b', 'c', 'z']`

For the life of me, I can't figure out why its alphabetizing things. Ideally, I want it as `['c','z','a','b']`

Comment: "For the life of me, I can't figure out why its alphabetizing things." - `dir` does that.

Comment: Per the documentation for [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir): "The resulting list is sorted alphabetically." Also note that depending on which version of Python 3 you're using, `dict`s may or may not be ordered by insertion order.

Comment: Very sassy sorry for not knowing that : o

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be using `dir` like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `__dict__` attribute:

```py
>>> class example:
        def __init__(self):
            self.c = 3
            self.z = 5
            self.a = 5
            self.b = 3

>>> example().__dict__
{'c': 3, 'z': 5, 'a': 5, 'b': 3}
>>> list(example().__dict__)
['c', 'z', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: It's worth noting that for Python 3.5 and below, dictionaries aren't guaranteed to maintain their insertion order. For those versions, the order of the attributes will be arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks Brian thats really helpful

Comment: Or more idiomatically, use `vars(example())`.